# How i specified a json path to get all the objects

Tags: python, json, path

I'm trying to get all the objects of a json path but I can't find a way to reference "all objects" within the same path

```
{
    "sfw-per-service-set-nat-pool": [
        {
            "pool-name": [
                {
                    "data": "11111111"
                }
            ],
            "translation-type": [
                {
                    "data": "2222222222"
                }
            ],
            "pool-address-range-list": [
                {
                    "pool-address-range": [
                        {
                            "data": "1.1.1.1-1.1.1.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "2.2.2.2-2.2.2.2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

This is a slice of the json i tried to reach in "pool-address-range and get all the objects in there but i always get the first or the second changing the json path by "1" in 'pool-address-range' "address=item['pool-address-range-list'][0]['pool-address-range'][1]['data']"

```
import json

with open('dd.json') as f:
 data = json.load(f)

for item in data['sfw-per-service-set-nat-pool']:
 name = item['pool-name'][0]['data']
 address=item['pool-address-range-list'][0]['pool-address-range'][0]['data']
 block= item['port-blocks-in-use'][0]['data']
 mblock= item['max-port-blocks-used'][0]['data']
```

The expected result must be all the objects in 'pool-address-range' with one iteration is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is get all addresses in `'pool-address-range-list'` you can use a list comprehension inside the loop. Technically it's another loop but it seems the best option for you.

```
addresses = [a['data'] for a in 
              item['pool-address-range-list'][0]['pool-address-range']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you want a set or a list, here's for a set:

```
result = set()
for pool_address_range in item["pool_address_range_list"]:
    for data_list in pool_address_range["pool-address-range"]:
        result.extend(data_list.values())
```

You could definitely do it in less lines but that code is readable, which is important with these crazy data structures you have there.